# The application being on the server works normally, but outside the server it is authorization loop

Tags: .net, angular, iis, identity

i have a problem.
I have uploaded my webapp along with identity to iis server which is on another computer. By connecting to the server (via rdp) I can easily log in to the application. On my computer, the login window displays without a problem, but after logging in, the application keeps reloading (doesn't go to the main page). In the console error, TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'roles').
What could be wrong? Is this a server configuration problem?

When connecting to the server, I have to be connected to the vpn, so the connection to the server is there. I tried uploading the application to another server and it works fine.

Comment: You need more information to troubleshoot this issue, you can check whether there is relevant information in the Event Viewer.

Comment: there is no information about it there ;/

Comment: ok i know the solution to the problem. in my case, the server where the application is hosted had the wrong time. After setting the current one (like my computer), the page loaded correctly